# how to delete duplicate records from a table

Tags: mysql

this is student table the student have two subjects maths and reading

the two subject are registered with same id i want to display only the maths students
here the condtion is primary key(sid,subject);

```
sid    fname   lname    subject  phno
---    -----   -----    -------- -----
1      vvk     v        math     4444
1      vvk     v        read     4444
2      hari    h        math     5555
2      hari    h        read     5555

3      kalyan  k        read     6666
```

How can I display a single record from the student has take subject math or read, like this:

```
1      vvk     v        math     4444 
2      hari    h        math     5555
3      kalyan  k        math     6666
```

here sid and subject are composite primary keys
if please write query to above result   in mysql

Comment: The question is not clear, what is the expected output of required query?

Comment: You should change your table structures this one is not normalized, ie make subject into a comma seperated subject list, or make a separate table that ties your person table to the subjects. http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/

Comment: There are no duplicates in there since the rows differ on subject column. How do you choose if you want math or read to be displayed?

Comment: Also your title says delete duplicates but you ask `How can I display` so which is it?

Comment: select * from student where subject in ('math','read') limit 1 offset 0

Answer (score 2):

Like i mention in my comment you should normalize your tables, your current structure is inefficent.

Until then use group along with group_concat it will group together the subjects into one field

```
SELECT 
    sid,fname,lname,phno,group_concat(subject) as subjects 
FROM 
    tablename 
GROUP BY 
    sid
```

Will produce something like

```
3  kalyan  k  6666  math,read
```